# How to get constant string array field into PDO/D7 db_query()?

Tags: pdo, drupal-7

First post here :)

Here's a valid MySQL query: `SELECT "'a','b'" AS FieldStrArray;`

(To enter as a string in PHP, remember the backslashes before double quotes.)

At least in Drupal 7's db_query(), this produces a fatal PDO exception, complaining that `'a','b'` is not a known field.

My question: how do I work around this apparent limitation of db_query()/PDO?

(Yes, I need a constant string array as one of the field results. This is a minimal replication of the problem... :) )

Any suggestions MOST welcome... including a) whether this is also a problem in PHP itself, b) how to report this as a bug to the Appropriate Authorities, c) Any creative ideas for a workaround assuming it is a real bug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not PDO/Drupal issue, but mysql one.
It seems that server is running in [ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes):

```
Treat “"” as an identifier quote character (like the “`” quote character) 
and not as a string quote character. You can still use “`” to quote identifiers 
with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotation
marks to quote literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier.
```

So, just take your advise and escape single quotes instead:

```
SELECT '\'a\',\'b\'' AS FieldStrArray
```

though I wonder why one would need such a thing from an SQL query. Some Drupal API limitations?